# Webpack bundle location of index.html when serving locally on Nativescript webview

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, nativescript

I have a NativeScript project, and an Angular project. I am creating a hybrid app. I use a WebView and put all of my bundled files from my Angular project into a folder in my NativeScript project.

When building the Angular project, I rewrite the base href dynamically like this

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

Here's how I load the bundles files.

```
let webview: WebView = this.webViewRef.nativeElement;
oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(
webview,
'~/www/app/index.html')
```

This works great! But when I use `--bundle` and add Webpack to the mix, my base href stops working and I get a `FILE NOT FOUND` error in my console.

Where is the new path located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Webpack to bundle the app, and Webpack ignores anything it thinks is irrelevant, you have to tell it your www sources are not irrelevant at all.

Open `webpack.config.js` and look for `CopyWebpackPlugin`. It may already contain rules like `{from: "fonts/**"}`, so in your case add `{from: "www/**"}` and you should be fine.